# How can I get my Javascript code to prefer cookies, but use local storage if cookies aren't present?

Tags: javascript, cookies, local-storage

I some Javascript code used on the web and also in an Android app using Phonegap.

At first, my code was set up to default to using local storage, and if there is no local storage, then default to cookies.

However, in a few contexts (too complicated to go into here), that is not working, so I want to see if I can go the other way: default to using cookies, and if cookies aren't possible, use local storage.

Really, it's only Android that is having trouble with cookies, so basically if my code is being used on an Android device, then I want to switch to local storage.

In any case, here is the code for setting cookie/local storage data that I have, but it's not working:

```
function setCookie(c_name, value, expiredays)
{
    var exdate = new Date();
    exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + expiredays);
    document.cookie = c_name + "=" + escape(value) +
    ((expiredays === null) ? "" : ";expires=" + exdate.toUTCString());
    if(document.cookie.length < 1 && typeof localStorage != "undefined")
    {
        localStorage.setItem(c_name, value);
    }
}
```

I think the problem might be where it says `document.cookie.length < 1`. Is that a reliable way of seeing if cookies are being set?

Bottom line: How can I reliably default to setting cookies, and use local storage as an alternative if cookies aren't present?

Comment: Can't you plugin via USB and use logcat?  What about alerts in the if statements?  You should start there and then update your question with what you find, at least with the alerts as they're quicker than figuring out logging if you haven't used it before. Good luck!

Comment: @jmort253: Even if I could set up a debugging environment, this is still something I'd like to be able to do with code. It is possible, I'm just not doing it right. So please focus on what the question is actually asking, and not get side tracked into other issues. Thanks.

Comment: Dave, my first step in *any* situation is to narrow the scope of the problem by figuring out what the code is actually doing. This isn't me getting sidetracked. This is the first step in the debugging process, and I'm human, like you, not a compiler. So, you could either use my first, quick suggestion and throw a few alert statements in your code to figure out whether or not localStorage is  *really* undefined or not, or you can just wait for some people to show up and guess. I apologize if my initial questions weren't clear. Good luck! :)

Comment: look here :) http://robert.accettura.com/blog/2012/01/17/localstorage-with-cookie-fallback/